# What is best way to return readonly with changeable objects?

Tags: c++

I'm having container of objects and i want to return only readonly list of them because objects are managed within container.

```
class Object;

class Container {
public:
   typedef list<Object*> Objects;

   // first method, probably slow
   Objects getObjects() { return this->objects; }
   // another method, but i don't know if it isn't lacking somewhere else
   Objects::iterator getObjectsIt() { return this->objects.begin(); }
   // OR any better method exists ??

private:
   Objects objects;
};
```

Comment: There's usually no need in C++ to say `this->`. This isn't Java or PHP :-)

Comment: I know, but i like writing `this`. ;)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want: no objects being added/removed from the list, or the objects already contained not being changed ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4797517/500104) has some interesting discussion on the paradoxic nature of this idea. If you can change the elements, you can change the list by simply reassigning the elements. What *exactly* do you want to be immutable? The size of the list? Okay, that's already fix. The members inside the list, but not their data? May be doable with a proxy object returned from a custom iterator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a special type of iterator that was incompatible with the member functions of your `list` which take iterators to mutate the list, so that you can access the objects through the iterator but not pass them to the functions that change the list they belong to.

That assumes that iterators don't remember what container they came from. If they do, then just make that special iterator class have no functions that can change its parent container.

Answer (score 1):

Return a `const_iterator` and declare the method const.

Comment: But the objects should be changle. Doesn't const_iterator affect that?

Comment: Now I'm baffled. What is it that you want? You already cannot mutate the container if you only expose iterators, so what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Miro You want a readonly list of changeable objects, so you want to be able to change the objects but not the list?