# What good is the c++'s `const` promise?

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to understand c++'s `const` semantics more in depth but I can't fully understand what really the constness guarantee worth is.
As I see it, the constness guarantees that there will be no mutation, but consider the following (contrived) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
  int i{0};

  void foo() {
    i = 42;
  };
};

class B {
public:
  A *a1;
  A a2;

  B() {
    a1 = &a2;
  }

  void bar() const {
    a1->foo();
  }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  std::cout << b.a2.i << std::endl; // output is 0

  b.bar();

  std::cout << b.a2.i << std::endl; // output is 42
}
```

Since `bar` is `const`, one would assume that it wouldn't mutate the object `b`. But after its invocation `b` is mutated.
If I write the method `foo` like this

```
void bar() const {
    a2.foo();
}
```

then the compiler catches it as expected.
So it seems that one can fairly easily circumvent the compiler with pointers. I guess my main question is, how or if I can be 100% sure that `const` methods won't cause any mutation to the objects they are invoked with? Or do I have completely false expectations about `const`?

**Why does c++ allow invocation of non-const methods over pointers in `const` methods?**

EDIT:

thanks to Galik's comment, I now found this:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4372.html

Well, this was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!
And I find Yakk's answer also very helpful, so I'll accept his answer.

Comment: The `const` following `bar` makes the guarentee that you will not mutate any of `B`'s members, which `bar` does not. To do that, it would have to modify the *value* of `a2` or the *address* of the pointer `a1`. All it did was modify the value of the `A` that `a1` was pointing at, which is legal.

Comment: @CoryKramer: except that `a1` is pointing at `a2`, and `a1` is declared as a pointer to a non-const `A`, so the compiler allows the call to `a1->foo()` since the pointed object is not `const` and `foo()` is not declared as `const`, but it can't validate that `a1` is actually pointing at a member `B` that should be const.  The code has **undefined behavior**.  When `bar()` calls `a2.foo()` instead, `a2` is being accessed via the `this` pointer, which is a `const B*` since `bar()` is `const`, so `a2` is `const` and the compiler fails the call since `foo()` is not declared as `const`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you cite the standard part which would claim this behavior undefined? I am pretty sure there are none.

Comment: @CoryKramer But `bar` did mutate the value of `a2`, because `a1` points to `a2`.

Comment: Why would people downvote the question? It rather interesting in my view (though not without a bit of provocation)

Comment: Don't understand the down votes??? Whats wrong with my question?

Comment: @bmk do not know. I am afraid, people just do not understand the question (and the fact that it was asked in a certain manner does not help)

Comment: This is a duplicate. Not of the currently proposed duplicate but I am having trouble finding the right one. It was asked just the other day. (this is closeish) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732648/c-preventing-const-methods-from-changing-data-through-a-member-pointer-or-refe

Comment: @SergeyA provocation, certain manner... Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @bmk, in the same question, you managed to admit your limited knowledge of C++ and fail the language for failing to fulfill the promise. Since most of the time here on SO such messages are complete rubbish, knee-jerk reaction is the downvoting. I am pretty sure, were you to ask the question differently, you would end up upvoted.

Comment: Using [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) allows the compiler to catch potential defects before run-time, such as mistakenly writing to an object or calling a function that writes to a constant object.

Comment: @SergeyA I can only say, wow!!! I didn't blame or attack the C++ language itself in any way. In fact, I was hoping that I would get some helpful explanations about `const` (what it actually promises and how I can use it more effectively) from more experienced C++ programmers... Instead you are bombarded with downvotes **without any sensible explanations or feedback**

Comment: what can I say? I disagree with downvotes. (I even upvoted). If it is any consolation, your score is still above 0 with 2 downvotes and 2 upvotes. Also, having an answer from @Yakk is a reward on it's own :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` tells the caller "this shouldn't mutate the object".

`const` helps the implementor with some errors where accidentally mutating state generates errors unless the implementor casts it away.

`const` data (not references, actual data) provides guarantees to the compiler that anyone who modifies this data is doing undefined behaviour; thus, the compiler is free to assume that the data is never modified.

`const` in the `std` library makes certain guarantees about thread safety.

All of these are uses of `const`.

---

If an object isn't `const`, anyone is free to `const_cast` away `const` on a reference to the object and modify it.

If an object is `const`, compilers will not reliably diagnose you casting away `const`, and generating undefined behavior.

If you mark data as `mutable`, even if it is also marked as `const` it won't be.

The guarantees that the `std` provides based off `const` are limited by the types you in turn pass into `std` following those guarantees.

---

`const` doesn't *enforce* much on the programmer.  It simply tries to help.

No language can make a hostlie programmer friendly; `const` in C++ doesn't try.  Instead, it tries to make it *easier* to write `const`-correct code than to write `const`-incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

Constness by itself doesn't guarantee you anything. It only takes away rights of specific code to mutate an object through a specific reference. It doesn't take away rights of other code to mutate the same object through other references, right under your feet.

Answer (score 1):

> So it seems that one can fairly easily circumvent the compiler with pointers.

That is indeed true.

> I guess my main question is, how or if I can be 100% sure that const methods won't cause any mutation to the objects they are invoked with?

The language guarantees that only in a local sense.

Your class is, indirectly, the same as the following:

```
struct Foo
{
  int* ptr;
  Foo() : ptr(new int(0)) {};

  void bar() const { *ptr = 10; }
};
```

When you use:

```
Foo f;
f.bar();
```

the member variable of `f` did not change since the pointer still points to the location after the call to `f.bar()` as it did before the call. In that sense, `f` did not change. But if you extend the "state" of `f` to include the value of what `f.ptr` points to, then the state of `f` did change. The language does not guarantee against such changes.

It's our job, as designers and developers, to document the "const" semantics of the types we create and provide functions that preserve those semantics.

> Or do I have completely false expectations about const?

Perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

When a class method is declared as `const`, that means the implicit `this` pointer inside the method is pointing at a `const` object and thus the method cannot alter any of the members of that object (unless they are explicitly declared as `mutable`, which is not the case in this example).

The `B` constructor is not declared as `const`, so `this` is of type `B*`, ie a pointer to a non-const `B` object.  So `a1` and `a2` are non-const, and `a1` is declared as a pointer to a non-const `A` object, so the compiler allows `a1` to be pointed at `a2`.

`bar()` is declared as `const`, so `this` is of type `const B*`, ie a pointer to a const `B` object.

When `bar()` calls `a1->foo()`, `a1` is `const` by virtue of `this` pointing at a `const B` object, so `bar()` can't change `a1` to point at something else.  But the `A` object that `a1` is pointing at is still deemed to be non-const by virtue of `a1`'s declaration, and `foo()` is not declared as `const`, so the compiler allows the call.  However, the compiler can't validate that `a1` is actually pointing at `a2`, a member of `B` that is supposed to be `const` inside of `bar()`, so the code breaks the `const` contract and has **undefined behavior**.

When `bar()` tries to call `a2.foo()` instead, `a2` is `const` by virtue of `this` pointing at a `const B` object, but `foo()` is not declared as `const`, so the compiler fails the call.

`const` is just a safety catch for well-behaving code.  It does not stop you from shooting yourself in the foot by using misbehaving code.

Answer (score -1):

This is a correct observation. In const-qualified functions (`bar` in your example) all data members of the class are behaving as if they are const data members *when accessed from this function*. With pointers, it means that the pointer itself is constant, but *not* the object it points to. As a matter of fact, your example can be very much simplified into:

```
int k = 56;
int* const i = &k;
*i = 42;
```

There is a big difference between pointer to constant object and constant pointer, and one needs to understand it, so that 'promises', which were not given in the first place, would not seem to be broken.